# Cómo puedo mostrar la colección relacionadas de mi base de dato en mongodb?

Tags: nodejs, mongodb, express, mongoose

Quiero realizar un `populate` a una colección de **mongodb** usando **moongoose**, hay alguna manera de realizar un `populate` a una colección en la que referencia a otra

La colección onhire hace una referencia a la colección servicio y la tabla servicio hace una referencia a la colección agencia.
Como puedo obtener los datos de la colección agencia desde la colección onhire

Esta es la coleccion inicial a la que quiero acceder

```js
import moongose, {Schema} from 'mongoose'

const AgenciaSchema = new Schema({
    agencia: {type:String,unique:true,required:true},
    representante: {type:String,required:true},
    rfc:{type:String,required:true},
    estado:{type:Number, default:0},
    createdAt:{type:Date, default:Date.now}
})

const agencia = moongose.model('agencia',AgenciaSchema)
export default agencia;
```

Esta es la colección que referencia a la colección inicial

```
import moongose,{Schema} from 'mongoose';

const ConfirmarServicioSchema= new Schema({
    cia : {type:Schema.ObjectId, ref:'compania',required:true},
    embarcacion : {type:Schema.ObjectId, ref:'embarcacion',required:true},
    agencia : {type:Schema.ObjectId, ref:'agencia',required:true},
    onhire : {type:Date},
    muelle: {type:String},
    programa: {type:String},
    detalles: {type:String, required:true},
    estado: {type:Number, default:1},
    tipo_servicio: {type:String},
    url_cotizacion: {type:String,unique:true},
    url_soporte: {type:String},
    createdAt: {type:Date, default:Date.now}
})


const confirmacionServicio = moongose.model('confirmarServicio',ConfirmarServicioSchema);
export default confirmacionServicio
```

Como puedo obtener los datos de la colección agencia, referenciando a la colección `confirmarServicio` donde esta referenciada la colección agencia???

```js
import mongoose, {Schema} from 'mongoose'

const onhireSchema = new Schema({
    servicio : {type:Schema.ObjectId, ref:'confirmarServicio',required:true,unique:true},
    estado: {type:Number, default:0},
    createdAt: {type:Date, default:Date.now},
    diesel: {type:Number, required:true},
    aceiteLubricante:{type:Number,required:true},
    aceiteLlubricante2: {type:Number},
    aceiteHidraulico: {type:Number},
    aceiteEngranes: {type:Number},
    aguaPotable: {type:Number, required:true},
    onhire: {type:Date, required:true}
})

const onhire = mongoose.model('onhire',onhireSchema)
export default onhire
```

Este es mi controlador, al final solo me muestra los resultados de servicio

```js
 list: async(req,res,next)=>{
        try{
            let valor = req.query.valor;
           
            const reg = await models.Onhire.find()
            .sort({'createdAt':-1})
            .populate('servicio')
            .populate('agencia')
            res.status(200).json(reg);
        }catch(e){
            res.status(500).send({
                message:'Ocurrio un error'
            });
            next(e);
        }
    },
```

Este es el resultado, yo quiero hacer un populate a la colección agencia

```js
[
    {
        "estado": 0,
        "_id": "5e07a051ee5d735bb8b317a2",
        "servicio": {
            "estado": 1,
            "_id": "5e079243adaae85518ba35c4",
            "cia": "5e06a2ced583f75200302bf5",
            "embarcacion": "5e069aab03e1c03cf0f1a69f",
            "agencia": "5e069d7a64c96e2dd83b995e",
            "onhire": "2020-03-15T06:00:00.000Z",
            "muelle": "Chiltepec",
            "programa": "cme-abktn-cme",
            "detalles": "cambio de guardia",
            "tipo_servicio": "terrestre",
            "url_cotizacion": "www.d,dmdmd",
            "url_soporte": "soporte",
            "createdAt": "2019-12-28T17:34:59.809Z",
            "__v": 0
        },
        "diesel": 1600,
        "aceiteLubricante": 2000,
        "aceiteHidraulico": 100,
        "aceiteEngranes": 123,
        "aguaPotable": 10,
        "onhire": "2019-03-18T06:00:00.000Z",
        "createdAt": "2019-12-28T18:34:57.187Z",
        "__v": 0
    }
]
```

Comment: Deberia funcionar con `populate('servicio.agencia')`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En vez de usar la consulta con `populate`, podrías realizarla con `aggregate`, te muestro:

```
models.Onhire.aggregate([
  //{$match:{}}, -> en el caso de que quieras filtrar
  {$sort:{'$createdAt':-1}},
  {
    $lookup:{  
        from:'confirmarServicio', 
        localField:'servicio',
        foreignField:'_id',
        as:'servicio'
    }
  },
  {$unwind:'$servicio'}, //Rebaja el array de un elemento a un objecto
  {
    $lookup:{
        from:'agencia',
        localField:'servicio.agencia',
        foreignField:'_id',
        as:'servicio.agencia'
    }
  },
  {$unwind:'$servicio.agencia'},  //Rebaja el array de un elemento a un objecto  
])
```

Al tener los `_id` indexados en las colecciones debería de ir rápida las consultas.

Esta query te daria este resultado como ejemplo:

```
[
    {
        "estado": 0,
        "_id": "5e07a051ee5d735bb8b317a2",
        "servicio": {
            "estado": 1,
            "_id": "5e079243adaae85518ba35c4",
            "cia": "5e06a2ced583f75200302bf5",
            "embarcacion": "5e069aab03e1c03cf0f1a69f",
            "agencia":{
                  _id: "5e069d7a64c96e2dd83b995e"
                  agencia: "string",
                  representante: "string",
                  rfc:"string",
                  estado:0,
                  createdAt:"2020-03-15T06:00:00.000Z
            },
            "onhire": "2020-03-15T06:00:00.000Z",
            "muelle": "Chiltepec",
            "programa": "cme-abktn-cme",
            "detalles": "cambio de guardia",
            "tipo_servicio": "terrestre",
            "url_cotizacion": "www.d,dmdmd",
            "url_soporte": "soporte",
            "createdAt": "2019-12-28T17:34:59.809Z",
            "__v": 0
        },
        "diesel": 1600,
        "aceiteLubricante": 2000,
        "aceiteHidraulico": 100,
        "aceiteEngranes": 123,
        "aguaPotable": 10,
        "onhire": "2019-03-18T06:00:00.000Z",
        "createdAt": "2019-12-28T18:34:57.187Z",
        "__v": 0
    }
]
```

Espero que esta query te ayude sino escribe de nuevo para ayudarte.

Un saludo